# Creating objects from xml error {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element"}

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to create a list of objects parsing an XML document.
Issue appears when projecting to `AdvertisementFullScreen`

I receive this error:

```
{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element"}
```

My code:

```
var advFs = loadedData.Element("xxx")
                           .Elements("advertisementsFullScreen")
                           .Elements("advertisement") // RESULT BELOW
                           .Select(x=>new AdvertisementFullScreen()
                           {
                               Id = (int)x.Element("id"),
                               ImageUrl = (string)x.Element("imageUrl"),
                               DisplayTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)x.Element("displayTime"))
                           }).ToList();
```

Result before projecting is:

```
[0] = <advertisement id="7001" imageUrl="C:/xxx/Test-data/data-offline/Assets/advertisementsFullScreen/1.png" displayTime="5" isSelfPromo="1"></advertisement>
```

Comment: Are you sure that casting something to int will convert it? You should use `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting `Element()`, but id, imageUrl, displayTime are not elements - they're attributes.

Modified query (just the important parts):

```
Id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
ImageUrl = (string)x.Attribute("imageUrl"),
DisplayTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)x.Attribute("displayTime"))
```